# Create symlinks on an external storage device that can work on any Linux machines?

Tags: symlink, external-hdd

An external storage device can be connected to different Linux or Unix machines, and I guess its mounting point may be different?

If yes, will symlinks that are stored on the device and link to files on the device become invalid when connecting the device to different *nix machines, because the mounting directory for the device changes?

If yes, how shall we create  symlinks on the device to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem if you use only relative symlinks within this volume.

```
ln -s ../otherdir/otherfile link
```

Comment: how to use relative symlinks?

Comment: It may require many `../`'s, is there some alternative way?

Comment: @Tim Why would that be a problem?

Comment: for example, using many `../`'s to go up to the mounting point of the device, and then down to some directory. This can be long.

Comment: @Tim And again: Who cares? Or are we talking about path length limits? It it feels better then you may chain symlinks. You can create a `../../` symlink `volume-root` in every directory and then create links like `ln -s volume-root/level1/level2/file filename`

Comment: The [`symlinks`](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/utils/file/symlinks-1.4.tar.gz) command can help you in doing that.

Comment: 'symlinks' doesn't exist by default. @StéphaneChazelas